# Python improve SVM or better with PCA

Tags: python, svm, pca

I want to do classification for 3D point cloud by SVM. I used python sklearn SVM directly. But the result seems very unreasonable. So I wonder if I should do segmentation firstly? May do the PCA transfer the 3D to 2d would be helpful. But I am not sure how to do it. I don't have plc package.

I attached my code below.

```
data1=np.loadtxt('filename')

'''data is a 20000*4d array with x,y,z information and indication for the 1st training sample'''

data2=np.loadtxt('filename2')

'''data is a 20000*4d array with x,y,z information and indication for the 2nd training sample'''

train=np.concatenate((data1,data2),axis=0)

from sklearn import svm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

clf1=svm.SVC(gamma=0.01, C=100)

x1,y1=train[:,0:2],train[:,3]

clf1.fit(x1,y1)

a1=clf1.predict(total_data[:,0:2])

'''then use a1 to display the results'''
```

Comment: "But the result seems very unreasonable. " What specifically do you mean by this? What is your objective function?

Comment: My function is based on the intensity and deviation value, I think that more question in my professional area instead of IT. The result seems very unreasonable means I use the correct train sample of leaf and trunk from a tree. But after predicting the total sample, there are a lot of the branches are regarded as leaf.

Comment: I would suggest a `gridsearch` or preferably a `RandomizedSearchCV` to optimize your hyperparameters according to your (sounds like non-standard) objective function. Creating a custom loss/scoring function you can pass to the `search` in `sklearn` is easy. Also maybe try normalizing your columns so they all are between 0 and 1 for example. All hyperparameters and preprocessing steps can be considered knobs to turn to optimize your objective